# how to convert number into strings

Tags: racket

I don't know what's wrong with my code or language, `(/ 1 2)` in racket will be calculated as 1/2, but it's printed as 0.5, I need to convert a number to string, so no slash, I know it's 1/2 cuz I saw the stepping.

I can't share my code I'm so sorry, this is an assignment question, but I'm asking general stuff so it's fine.

Comment: You should share the part of your code that's causing the error, you don't need to post everything, but without code how can we reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can split a number into numerator and denominator, and then add the "/" between their string representation to get a fraction.

```
(define n1 1/2)
(define n2 (/ 1 2))

(define (frac->str n)
  (string-append
   (number->string (numerator n))
   "/"
   (number->string (denominator n))))


(frac->str n1)
; => "1/2"
(frac->str n2)
; => "1/2"
```